# MessageDialog in c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, namespaces

I've bought book "Heads up c#". I'm using Windows 10 and VS 2015 so there is only WPF, but book is designed for XAML...

Chapter 11 demands these namespaces: using Windows.System, Windows.Storage, Windows.UI.Popups but I can't find them in WPF, these are for: MessageDialog, UIcommand, IStorageFile, FileOpenPicker, is there way to add them to WPF project?

//edit
Thank you for help, I've patched VS for UWP, it works.
But now my problem is scalling:
The page size is set to 800x600, these are columns:

```
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Title is in 1st row, content is in 2nd, button(save,load) is in 3rd, it looks like grid it wouldn't exist:

[Thats with normal size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBDrC.png)

[After size change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bgHW.png)

In WPF it worked ;/

Answer (score 1):

For asynchronous dialog try this:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using System.Windows;

// 1. call method with message window
ShowMyDialogWindow();

// 2. use async and await with Task, create your message window here.
public async void ShowMyDialogWindow()
{
    MessageBoxResult result= await Task.Run(() => MessageBox.Show("Arre you happy?", 
        "My window name", MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel));
        switch (result)
        {
            case MessageBoxResult.None:
                break;
            case MessageBoxResult.Yes:
                // do something
                break;
            case MessageBoxResult.No:
                // do something
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    // This line will be executed after windows closed you can use it for 
    // something (close resource, stop timer ...)
    DoSomeThingHereToo();
}

// message window do not block your app, app will running other task.
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, these classes work only with Universal Windows Platform. You can try creating UWP app maybe, or what you need is a WPF?

Answer (score 0):

Angelin N. is correct, those classes aren't available in WPF (at least not without significant hacking). You need to create a UWP project to run the examples in that book, it sounds like.

Much of what you're looking for does exist in WPF though. There's really very little you can do in UWP that you can't do in WPF. For example, `System.Windows.MessageBox` gives you message boxes. `System.IO.File` gives you access to all file IO (equivalent to `IStorageFile`). File pickers are available through `Microsoft.Win32.FileDialog`. There are many equivalents between the two platforms.

If you're looking to make applications for Windows 7, you need to use WPF. However if you are ok with your apps only working on Windows 10 or higher, then UWP is probably best.

Comment: The reason I needed them was mainly asynchronous dialog, I've tried to make async with MessageBox.show() but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you be more clear on what you're trying to do? Asynchronous programming is definitely possible in WPF. You usually need to make use of the Dispatcher object. For example, Dispatcher.InvokeAsync will let you perform pretty much any kind of operation, including ShowDialog, in an asynchronous manner.